# Design of hard drive RAIDs

Tags: sql-server, configuration, raid

My task is to reconfigure a main server that houses the company's applications and data.  The server is capable of handling everything.  I wanted to find out if anyone has a suggestion on the best hard drive configuration.

They have 2 300GB hard drives and 8 600GB hard drives.  Currently they are configured as the following:

- 2 300GB (OS, RAID 0+1)
- 2 600GB (Hyper-V Virtual Disks, RAID 0+1)
- 2 600GB (QuickBooks & Personal User Data, RAID 0+1)
- 2 600GB (Files Used/Stored, RAID 0+1)
- 2 600GB (Files Used/Stored & Exchange Database, RAID 0+1)

This is a Windows 2012 R2 member server contains the following applications:

- Hyper-V with RemoteFX,
- Exchange 2013,
- Software IP-PBX,
- QuickBooks Data Files,
- SQL Server 2014,
- User Files, Used/Stored files.

Any suggestions on best performance and best configuration would be greatly appreciated.  Also, please suggest what I should to do to back up their data so that I can re-do their drives without losing any of their data.  SQL Server is installed but the databases are empty, they haven't used that yet, so I could just uninstall.

Comment: RAID 0+1 on two disks? How? Both RAID0 and RAID1 require two disks, so RAID 0+1 would require four...